# Как избавиться от повторной работы кода при загрузке страниц Ajax?

Tags: javascript

Дело в том, что подгружаю страницы через ajax, просто вставив тег скрипт на загружаемую страницу(таких страниц много), и первая работает нормально, но все последующие начинают выполнять код файла js и дебагера, выглядит вот так[image: вот так]

Comment: Приведите код, пожалуйста

Comment: Я не стал сильно мудрить и просто подключаю js файл при запросе html по ajax <script class="script" type="text/javascript" src="../js/case.js"></script> но потом, если я захожу на вторую такую же страницу и там заного подключается js файл, но код вот так выполняется 2 раза

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете поменять подход , то есть не подгружать страницы а подгружать контент страниц , а шапку и футер оставить , и в них уже подключить скрипты и css ,
Или попробуйте использовать 
Обернуть скрипт в функцию 
И вызывать внутри этой конструкции

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { alert("DOM готов!"); });
```

Плюс ещё можно сделать проверку дав телегу `<script id="my">`  айди
И проверить если такой скрипт есть то не подключать